# No data is been shown inside my Moderm Search Web Part Cards

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, pnp

I have the following setting inside my PnP - Search Result : -

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Then i chose the Cards layout >> and i define to show FileName + Path >> but the cards will be shown as empty (except for the document icon).. any advice please?

[image]

Comment: I suggest you also ask questions here: https://github.com/microsoft-search/pnp-modern-search/issues

Comment: @AmyJiang_MSFT asked there already never got an answer